# How to query a DB table from C++

Tags: c++, sql

I have C++ code, and from it I need to access the DB and make a query in table (with name NECE_TABLE, which has 2 columns - IntID and Status).

Here I need to get "status" column value from DB table (NECE_TABLE) using the IntID from C++ code.

Any help will be greatly helpful. Thanks in advance

Comment: What kind of database? SQLite? Postgres? MySQL? MongoDB?

Comment: Would also be helpful to know which platform you're on. Windows? Linux? etc.

Comment: Edited the tags - the OP is using Oracle 10g Enterprise :-) Not sure what OS though.

Comment: Its database-MySQL and Platform-Linux.

Thanks in advance

Comment: @Rag MySQL? In other comments you've said Oracle10g! Which is it?

Comment: @Rag Well, between my answer and @JamWaffles answer, you should be able to at least have a go at writing some code to connect to either an Oracle or MySQL database!

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very vague, but in summary you need to:

- Use an appropriate client library supported by your database to connect to that database using some user credentials with appropriate permissions for SELECTing from your table
- Execute a [SQL select](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select.asp) to fetch the data you want

There's some confusion as to which database you're using.

**If you're using Oracle**, you can use the [OCCI client library](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14294/introduction.htm) to connect to the database and execute SQL statements. See section 2 of the linked document, where it describes connecting to a database and executing SQL queries.

Comment: Hi... thanks.. I am using using below database.
Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this link](http://www.suite101.com/content/using-a-mysql-databases-with-c-a70097) - it's a simple tutorial on how to get started with MySQL and C++. You say you are using vanilla SQL in your tags, but the two should be compatible as long as you stick to the more basic queries.

Comment: Hi JamWaffles.. Thanks for replying..
I am using Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition.

I just need to query this in my C++ code --> 
Eg:
SELECT STATUS from NECE_TABLE where INT_ID=56;